# Text not in the center of the row if single line

Tags: java, android, android-studio, layout

I'm having issues with centering my text in for a row in TextView.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="25dp"
android:paddingBottom="25dp"
android:paddingLeft="25dp"
android:paddingRight="25dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center"
>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"

        android:text="Loading..."
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/listTxtColor"
        android:textSize="18dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This seems to work for text that runs over two lines but not for text that runs on one line.
[image: Screenshot]

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row_declaration, R.id.tvTitle, treatyList);
```

Comment: Did you tried setting TextView.layout_width="wrap_content"?

Comment: Some screenshots may help, and where do you use this layout?

Comment: Yes, have tried using "warp_content" with no success.

Comment: Updated with screenshot

Comment: Change android:layout_width="match_parent" to android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Comment: your xml code doesn't match with your screenshot post whole layout

Comment: try setting         android:gravity="center"

Comment: Are you using a `ListView` or something?

Comment: please post your whole code.

Comment: Yes, using ListView

Comment: Just to add context - this is the XML view my adaptor is using for each row of the list view.
This is using a ArrayAdapter.

Comment: @Bigboytony add the complete code of your XML layout and code file where you are using TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Surprised this only has 49 views in almost 4 years, I had the same issue. The following was enough to keep my text centered in the textview for multiple lines, but not one line, just like in your image:

```
flavorTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
flavortextParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
flavortextParams.topMargin = 0;
flavorTextView.setLayoutParams(flavortextParams)
```

To get centered text for just one line I had to add:

```
flavortextParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
```

This is because multiple lines of text automatically sets the textview width to the screenwidth, so the textview (and the wrapped text) is automatically centered. This isn't the case with just one line of text unless it happens to extend to the width of the screen.